# How can I show date in text using DateTimepicker in ReactNative?

Tags: react-native

I am using DateTimePicker and I have to show a date. What I have to do is when the user clicks on TextView, then DateTimepicker opens and shows date again in TextView. To do this I've tried the following:

code of DateTimePicker:

```
constructor(){ 
  super();
  this.state = { 
    PickerValueHolder : '' ,
    isDateTimePickerVisible: false,
    date: 'Birthday'
  }
}

_showDateTimePicker = () => this.setState({ 
  isDateTimePickerVisible: true });
_hideDateTimePicker = () => this.setState({ 
  isDateTimePickerVisible: false});

_handleDatePicked = (date) => {
  this.setState({date: date})
  this._hideDateTimePicker();
};

<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._showDateTimePicker}>
  <Text style={{marginLeft:20}}>{this.state.date}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
<DateTimePicker
  isVisible={this.state.isDateTimePickerVisible}
  onConfirm={this._handleDatePicked}
  onCancel={this._hideDateTimePicker/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by using changing folowing code

```
 _handleDatePicked = (date) => {
  var date = new Date(date);
  dobValue= isNaN(date) ? this.state.dob :date.getDate() + "/"+ 
  parseInt(date.getMonth()+1) +"/"+ date.getFullYear();
    if (! isNaN(date)) {
    this.setState({ dob: dobValue });
  }
  this._hideDateTimePicker();
  };
```